# how to generate JPG files from a View and be able to display progress?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My android app generates 30 .jpg files from a Class that extends View.  The app works but, on my ASUS Transformer tablet, takes about 17 seconds to complete.  I would like to gray-out the Button that initiates the .jpg generation process, but since it is on the UI thread, I cannot gray-out the Button or show status during the 17 second delay.  I've tried several ways to put the process in a runnable, off the UI thread.  None have worked.  The code is simple:

In the main Class, I have the following Button and method code:

```
writeAllJpgPages = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.writeAll);
writeAllJpgPages.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        jpgtest.scrollTo(0, pageSize * i);
        jpgtest.invalidate();
        // give page number
        jpgtest.createJpg(i + 1);
    }
    pageNumber.setSelection(29);
    popUp("" + i + " pages written.");
}
```

});

where jpgtest is an instance of the Class, CanvJpg extends View. The method in that Class that generates the .jpg files is as follows:

```
public void createJpg(int page) {
    if (page > 0 && page < 31) {
        try {
            fio = new FileOutputStream(patt[page - 1]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            popUp("File NOT FOUND exception on " + patt[page - 1] + ":  " + e);
        }
        try {  // creates the jpg file:
            getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fio);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            popUp("CanvJpg Class: Exception on creating " + patt[page - 1] + "\n" + e);
        }
    } else {
        popUp("page out of range 1 to 30:  " + page + ".  No file created.");
    }
}

private void popUp(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The code works fine, I just want to be able to gray-out the Button and show progress following the pressing of the writeAllJpgPages Button.  I think I need to get the processing off the UI thread, but how?

Comment: In the `onClick()` event, before the `for` loop, disable the Button. Don't forget to re-enable it after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to be doing image processing on the UI thread. This will lead to ANR errors and general unresponsiveness.

The simplest way to move it off thread is to use an `AsyncTask` to define your `createJpg` method.

AsyncTasks define 4 methods; `onPreExecute`, `doInBackground`, `onProgressUpdate`, and `onPostExecute`.

These are relatively self-explanatory. `doInBackground` runs in the background thread and is where you should put the meat of your image processing code. The other methods all run on the UI thread and can be used to update your UI (e.g. graying out the button in `onPreExecute` and re-enabling it on `onPostExecute`, or updating a progress spinner in `onProgressUpdate`).

For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check AsyncTask, it's a built in tool from Android SDK that let you do task in background and update your views

Answer (score 0):

The process is not very elegant, as `.scrollTo()`, `.invalidate` and `getDrawingCache()` must be called in the UI thread, which will effectively block it. Also, I understand that user interaction must be somehow blocked, as you're scrolling what I understand is a visible view (`jpgtest`) and taking screenshots.

So, all in all maybe @Rotwang 's is the "less bad" solution (quick and dirty).

An alternative could be to do all this calls to the UI methods in an AsyncTask as @gcgrant suggests: UI calls in `onPreExecute`, compression and saving of the file in `doInBackground` (i.e. you will have to split your `createJpg()` method).

Finally, to avoid out of memory issues, I suggest to repeat the previous process for each image, instead of taking all the screenshots in the `onPreExecute` and them compress them all in the `doInBackground` step. This will be done from inside a Thread (I know, this is getting ugly):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Disable the button and then...
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                // Asynctask
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This will start a background thread, that for each image will start an AsyncTask that will:

- Scroll, invalidate and take a screenshot in the UI thread,
- Compress and save the image in a second background thread.

I know, not elegant at all, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

I used CountDownTimer to place each write of the 30 .jpg pages in a separate onTick call, spacing the ticks at 750 msec.  This allows time to disable the initiating button using setClickable to false, graying out the button, and progress updates after each of the 30 writes of a .jpg file.  Of course there are down sides, such making the user wait, no matter how quick the device is, etc.

The answer to disable the button didn't work, because being on the UI thread, the setClickable(false) didn't post until after all 30 .jpgs got generated.

I couldn't get the AsyncTask solution to work because once I passed the view instance to the AsyncTask, it said that view could only be accessed by the UI thread.